# how to create nb2listw object and perform Lee's test for two variables?

Tags: r, spatial, correlation

I am trying to compute Lee's statistics for two variables. Actually, I have two points and some observations for each of these two points.

My problem is that I can't create weight matrix using nb2listw. I have tried to create neighbors based on two points x and y coordinates. 
Here, d0086 and d0126 are my two points.

```
d0086$x <- 227
d0086$y <- 180
d0126$x <- 282
d0126$y <- 149

cords <- cbind(d0086$x,d0126$x)
cords <- as.matrix(cords)
nb <-dnearneigh(coords,0,1000)
```

then when I try to run the

```
nb2listw(nb, style="W")
```

but I am getting error

```
error in nb2listw(dnearneigh(cords, 0, 1000), zero.policy = TRUE) : No valid observations
```

I am not sure how to proceed. Can you help me give me suggestions to perform Lee's test for two variables?

https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/spdep/versions/0.6-13/topics/lee

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `coords` matrix needs the coordinates of the two points:

```
d0086 <- c(227, 180)
d0126 <- c(282, 149)   
coords <- cbind(d0086,d0126)

nb <- dnearneigh(coords,0,1000) 
nb2listw(nb, style="W")


###############
Characteristics of weights list object:
Neighbour list object:
Number of regions: 2 
Number of nonzero links: 2 
Percentage nonzero weights: 50 
Average number of links: 1 

Weights style: W 
Weights constants summary:
  n nn S0 S1 S2
W 2  4  2  4  8
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment! However, it created only 2 points. I want create row(d0086) number of points with same coordinate values. Otherwise, I cannot call Lee test. Can you give any hint? Thanks, I edited your code as follows:

Comment: d0086$x <- c(227,180)
d0126$x <- c(282,149)
cords <- cbind(d0086$x,d0126$x)
nb <- dnearneigh(coords,0,1000)
lw <- nb2listw(nb, style="W")

Lxy<-lee(d0086$c0086ts, d0126$c0126ts,lw, length(d0086$c0086ts), zero.policy=TRUE)

Comment: For a more detalied help you should post you data